# iexpress exits with code 1. Where do I find logs for failure

Tags: iexpress

I am running

```
iexpress /n /q setupfile.sed
```

This one exited with code 1. Where do I find logs for failure? I tried to find command switches for verbose log and couldnot find anything.

Comment: Perhaps remove `/Q` and see if you get an error when running interactively. I don't think there is any logging for `iexpress.exe` (at least, none I could ever find).